# Unsupported value: "Always": supported values: "OnFailure", "Never"

Tags: docker, cron, openshift

I am trying to set up a Cron Job in OpenShift but it fails with the following message:

> 2020-02-27T14:01:18.7412341Z * spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.containers: Required value
>   2020-02-27T14:01:18.7412503Z * spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy: Unsupported value: "Always": supported values: "OnFailure", "Never"

and my CronJob-file goes as this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-cjob
  labels:
    job-name: my-cjob
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *" 
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:         
        metadata:
          name: my-cjob
          labels:
          job-name: my-cjob
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: my-cjob
            image: my-image-name
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

What am I doing wrong? I have taken great inspiration from OpenShift:

[image: snippet from OpenShifts own site]

found here: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/3.11/html/developer_guide/dev-guide-cron-jobs

What am I not seeing?

Comment: Hi, btw you need to ident your label `job-name: my-cjob`

Comment: What version of OpenShift are you trying this on? `oc version`

Comment: @WillGordon OpenShift 3.11

Comment: @SureshVishnoi yeah okay. I  guess "job-name" is redundant then. I will do that, but it fails at containers the first time, which I don't understand. Especially the part about restartPolicy shouldn't be "Always", when I never set it to always...

Comment: To be honest, copy/pasting _exactly_ what you have above, into a file and then running `oc create -f cron.yml` worked for me a on 3.11.154 cluster. Could it be possible, since this is a `beta` API object, that the object creation is blocked on your cluster?

Comment: I also see the documentation refers to CronJobs as `v2alpha1.CronJob` in the 3.11 docs: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/rest_api/apis-batch/v2alpha1.CronJob.html

Comment: It's also possible the version of your `oc` tools isn't up to date for your cluster version.

Comment: @WillGordon wow, that are some scenarios, that I need to check out. Regarding the `beta` option - how can I go around that? I can see the other 'jobs' we have in our project, that work well, are `batch\v1` - don't know how to find out if the cluster is blocking the beta-versions. This is the only Cron Job...
So I should try with `apiVersion: v2alpha1.CronJob` instead? Honestly I just used the `batch/v1beta1` since it's the one used in the example in the link I posted.
Don't know how to check my `oc` tools either - should I run `oc config view`?

Comment: `oc version` should give you everything you need, start there

Comment: @WillGordon Allright, finally got to do oc version, at it states locally: `oc v3.10.127` , `features: Basic-Auth` and on server `oc v3.11.135` - does that state anything useful? The error messages I get seems a bit misleading

Comment: is it the missing "command"-value?  That seems to be the only thing missing in regards to the example from redhat. But in my eyes it's "optional"..

Comment: Try updating your local `oc`, see if that helps

Comment: @WillGordon I've found the error. It all came down to a missing indent.

Comment: Odd, considering I copy/pasted exactly what you had above and it worked for me. I wonder if somehow my editor auto-fixed the indent. Either way, glad you got it sorted!

Comment: @WillGordon which editor do you use? Now I get a "Cannot determine if job needs to be started. Too many missed start time (> 100). Set or decrease .spec.startingDeadlineSeconds or check clock skew." message - that's a whole new topic.. And googling it, I can see that the reasons for this is many.

Comment: I just use Sublime Text ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Very odd about the `DeadlineSeconds`...I can only _assume_ it's something related to your nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer... A bit confusing, especially when reading the error message, but Suresh Vishnoi was right:

It all came down to a missing "tab" / indent:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-cjob
  labels:
    job-name: my-cjob
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *" 
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:         
        metadata:
          name: my-cjob
          labels:
            job-name: my-cjob   <<<< Here was the missing indent!
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: my-cjob
            image: my-image-name
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

My theory is that the missing indent had confused the error-handler and therefore it for some reason thought the issue was in regards to the next step, the containers.

I'll leave this here if anyone else should be hitting this (stupid) error message and think that it has anything to do with containers or restartpolicy...